# How do i reset leak period?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

How can i restore a previous leak period?

Example, we have our server set-up to calculate the leak period based on version number.  Unfortunately someone bumped the version number of the project prematurely.  We restored the version number and the change is reflected in the project history,  but the leak period metrics were not restored.  Currently the newer,erroneous version number is being used to label the leak period.

Side question: How does sonarqube detect a "newer" version number?  Does it just look at the changed string or does it have to be higher?

Using microsoft windows as an example:  If the project version change from 3,3.11, NT, 98, 98 r2, ME, xp, 7, 8, 8.1, 10  how will sonarqube calculate leak periods?

Comment: have you run a new analysis since you dropped the bad snapshot?

Comment: Yes,  the project version does reset (and it is reflected in history) but the leak period remained set to the bad version.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by going to the project history and deleting the snapshot that caused the version number to change.  It seems to revert to previous leak period next time the project is scanned.

I'm not sure there is any other bad side effect to this yet, but at least the reports are more correct than before.